# Best way to define many composed objects in C++?

Tags: c++, templates, memory-management, composition

I'm a vegetarian, so suppose we have vegetables:

```
class Vegetable {}; // base class for vegetables

class Tomato : public Vegetable {};
class Potato : public Vegetable {};
class Carrot : public Vegetable {};
class Broccoli : public Vegetable {};
```

And suppose we wanna make meals with them:

```
class Meal {}; // base class for meals

class Soup : public Meal {
    ...
    Soup(Vegetable *veg1, Vegetable *veg2) : veg1(veg1), veg2(veg2) {};
};

class Salad : public Meal {
    ...
    Salad(Vegetable *veg1, Vegetable *veg2, Vegetable *veg3) : veg1(veg1), veg2(veg2), veg3(veg3) {};
};

class VeggieBurger : public Meal {
    ...
    VeggieBurger(Vegetable *veg) : veg(veg) {};
};
```

Now we'd like to define different meals with different vegetable combinations in a cookbook:

```
std::vector<Meal *> cookbook;

cookbook.push_back(new Soup(new Tomato, new Potato));
cookbook.push_back(new Soup(new Potato, new Broccoli));
cookbook.push_back(new Salad(new Tomato, new Carrot, new Broccoli));
cookbook.push_back(new Salad(new Tomato, new Potato, new Tomato));
cookbook.push_back(new Salad(new Broccoli, new Potato, new Carrot));
cookbook.push_back(new VeggieBurger(new Potato));
// many more meals...
```

So we are creating many little objects on the heap that are getting composed together via constructor arguments and pushed onto a std::vector at runtime. Obviously the downside of this design is, that we have to manage the memory ourselves and delete the Vegetable objects in our meals destructor and delete our cookbook meals somewhere when it goes out of scope.

So a possible design choice would be to use smart pointers to out source the burden of doing memory management for our meals and vegetables.

But I'm wondering if it is possible to compose the cookbook at compile time, maybe with some kind of template magic? The cookbook does not necessarily have to be a std::vector but we still like to be able to iterate over it, get the Meal objects and call member functions on a composed meal. Are there better ways to do it?

Comment: Noting of course that tomato is a fruit. :-P Also, take a look at [Boost.Fusion](http://www.boost.org/libs/fusion/)'s `boost::fusion::vector<>`.

Comment: You may have already headed down a bad design path.  Is your example accurate in that you want to define many classes, all empty?  And that you want to allocate many instances of the same empty class, e.g. `Tomato`?

Comment: In the real world implementation a `Vegetable` has state and member functions.

Comment: What exactly is the problem with the current implementation? How many meals are put in the cookbook? Is your program slow at the beginning as it does all the calls to `cookbook.push_back` ? Do you want to speed this up? ("I'm wondering if it is possible to compose the cookbook at compile time")

Comment: To me 'Carrot' is a name property of vegetable not a unique type in itself - will Carrot really have methods different from Vegetable?

Comment: Yes, a Carrot has different methods. This whole vegetable thing is only a made up example to describe my problem more easily. In my real program I'm writing a Game Boy emulator and the vegetables are registers or memory locations, the meals are CPU instructions and the cookbook is a collection of my CPU instructions. But I found it too difficult to explain. My goal is a simpler design. I like the idea about generating code. But maybe it is wrong to create the cookbook in C++ code at all, maybe it should be a text file which should be parsed at runtime to create the cookbook definition

Comment: Are the objects modifiable at runtime? You say these classes will have 'state and methods', but can you tell us that they are all const methods?

Comment: The objects don't change itself (the "cookbook" is a fixed definition) but they are changing values of references they contain (in my case different registers of the CPU or memory locations) - so I don't think they are really const. Imagine the constructor of `Tomato` has a parameter to e.g. an `Origin` object which is getting changed on some method calls of `Tomato`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found that code generation is becoming an incredibly useful tool for me. Maybe write a short program, perhaps even just a script, than will generate the boilerplate code for you.

Any time you add to your cookbook, you run the program/script, which will generate the headers for each meal and the header, maybe even some of the source, for the cookbook itself.

How in-depth you get with your generation is up to you. You could just edit the code generator's source to add new meals, you could do some simple text based parsing, or, if it's really worth the time and effort to maintain, turn your code generator into an editor (with code generation as its output).

At least one very well know AAA game engine actually generates C++ header files for any scripts that are marked to interface with native code. From there, a macro in a source file implements the boilerplate methods. The rest of the methods are implemented by the developers.

Update:
C++11 actually has support for [variadic template arguments](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variadic_template#C.2B.2B11). I don't have any experience with C++11, so I'm not sure if variadic template arguments would support what we're looking at.

Comment: +1 http://pragprog.com/the-pragmatic-programmer/extracts/tips "Write Code That Writes Code"

Answer (score 1):

Well, with C++11 you can do:

```
std::vector<Meal *> cookbook = {
    new Soup(new Tomato(), new Potato()),
    new Soup(new Potato(), new Broccoli()),
    new Salad(new Tomato(), new Potato(), new Tomato()),
    // etc
};
```

Of course, this still ends up running operator new and the constructors at runtime rather than compile time, but is at least a bit more compact.

**edit**

Unfortunately C++11 does not provide a way to create an unnamed object of static storage duration and take its address for use in such a construct.  You need to give such objects a name, something like:

```
static Tomato tomatoes[] = {
    { /* first tomato initializer */ },
    { /* second */ },
    /* more */
}
static Potato potatoes[] = { ...
static Soup soups[] = { 
    { &tomatoes[0], &potatoes[0] },
    ...
static Salad salads[] = {
    { &tomatoes[4], &potatoes[2], &tomatoes[5] },
    ...
std::vector<Meal *> cookbook = {
    &soups[0], &soups[1], &soups[2], ...
    &salads[0], &salads[1], ...
```

This is extremly error prone, but is a good choice for what kind of C++ code to generate if you follow Sion Sheevok's answer.

Comment: Perhaps `constexpr` might help to do all of this at runtime? Instead of `new Tomato`, write a function `constexpr Tomato newTomato` which creates a Tomato *by value*. Bear with me while I do some experiments.

Comment: @AaronMcDaid: Can't store varying types in a container except by pointer (except via boost::variadic), so you won't get very far.

Comment: @MooingDuck, I see now. I did a few `sizeof` experiments and I realized the array elements were clobbering each other. Never mind. I should delete my answer :-(

Answer (score 0):

Well, if it's all known at compile time, then here's a bad idea:

```
template <class... Types>
struct cookbook {
    std::tuple<Types...> data;

    template<int i, bool safe>
    struct safe {
        static const Meal* get(const std::tuple<Types...>& data) 
        {return std::get<i, Types...>(data);}
    };
    template<int i, false>
    struct safe {
        static const Meal* get(const std::tuple<Types...>& data) 
        {return NULL;}
    };

    class iterator {
    protected:
        friend cookbook;
        cookbook* parent;
        int index;
    public: 
        iterator(cookbook* p, int i) : parent(p), index(i) {}
        iterator& operator++() {++index; return *this;}
        iterator& operator+=(int i) {index += i; return *this;}
        const Meal& operator*() const {
             switch (i) {
             case 0: return p->safe<0, Types...>::get(data);
             case 1: return p->safe<1, Types...>::get(data);
             case 2: return p->safe<2, Types...>::get(data);
             case 3: return p->safe<3, Types...>::get(data);
             case 3: return p->safe<4, Types...>::get(data);
             case 3: return p->safe<5, Types...>::get(data);
             }
        }
        bool operator==(const iterator& r) {
            return parent==r.parent && index==r.index;
        }
        bool operator!=(const iterator& r) {
            return index!=r.index || parent!=r.parent;
        }
    };
    iterator begin() {return iterator(this, 0);}
    iterator end() {return iterator(this, tuple_size<Types...>::value+1);}
};
```

This actually creates a cookbook object with (effectively) a *member* for each `Meal` type, and a hard-coded iterator to grab each one.

I doubt this will actually compile since I've never tried such a thing and have no compiler with variadic templates.   Also, I only implemented a small part of it.  You could do another layer of this with

```
 template<class RecipieType, class....Types>
 struct Recipie : RecipieType {
      //same as above
```

which would get you

```
 #define soup1types Tomoato,Potato
 #define soup2types Potato,Broccoli
 #define salad1types Tomato,Carrot,Broccoli
 #define cooktypes Recipie<Soup,soup1types>\
                   Recipie<Soup,soup2types>\
                   Recipie<Salad,salad1types>
 cookbook<cooktypes> book; //bam. recipies exist.
```

Also, people may hate you (and me) when they see this.

Comment: Im told boost::fusion does this but better and safer.  As always, boost has what you need.

Answer (score -1):

Even with templates you'd need some sort of type erasure to put the resulting instantiation somewhere. You could have a `Meal` base class which takes its ingredients via template arguments. For example:

```
template <typename... T>
class Salad: public Meal {
};

std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Meal>> cookbook;
cookbook.push_back(std::unique_ptr<Meal>(new Salad<Tomato>()));
cookbook.push_back(std::unique_ptr<Meal>(new Salad<Tomato, Carrot>()));
cookbook.push_back(std::unique_ptr<Meal>(new Salad<Tomato, Tomato, Carrot>()));
```

Of course, to be useful in some shape or form you'd still need to provide some accessors to retrieve the various ingredients. To do this, you'd need to restore the original `Salad` instantiation - except that it is lost. You might create a virtual function in `Meal` which is implemented in `Salad` and assembles the various incredients.

Comment: If you actually want to store arguments of type `Tomato` etc. you would need a `std::tuple`.

Comment: Why so cumbersome? You can say `cookbook.emplace_back(new Salad<Tomato>());` etc.